# Downloading NDVI time-series using python API

Tags: python, sentinel-2

Are there examples of an API where I can pass a lat, lon, date-range and get NDVI time-series for that location based on Sentinel-2 data without having to download entire tiles and without having to run on GEE? I haven;t seen any complete examples of this e.g. with sentinel-sat API

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you referring to a point-based time-series?
If so, Sentinel Hub's Statistical API would surely fit:
https://www.sentinel-hub.com/develop/documentation/api/fis-request

You will need to configure a layer, which will return [actual NDVI values](https://www.sentinel-hub.com/faq/how-do-i-get-actual-ndvi-values) and then use this in the request.

The Python integration is available here:
https://sentinelhub-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/fis_request.html

(Disclaimer: I am working at Sinergise, which is operating Sentinel Hub)

Comment: thanks for your help with this, is there  a related API that can extract time-series for a polygon (e.g. geojson format)

Comment: The above mentioned Statistical API can do this, you just need to provide GEOMETRY instead of BBOX.